# Installing JavaScript AWS SDK for NativeScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, nativescript

I'm trying to use AWS-SNS in NativeScript. AWS SDK is available for JavaScript.Can anybody know how to install AWS SDK for NativeScript.

I tried by installing aws-sdk for javascript on Node.js. Reference link is "https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk".
But because of below code

require("aws-sdk")

In Nativescript an error saying **Failed to find module: "crypto"** is coming.With a bit of search in internet, I found that crypto module support is not added in Nativescript.

Now I'm wondering are there any other ways.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Clarify you question : What's the link of your package ? Do you have a link for the documentation ? Do you have an error message ? What did you try ?

Comment: I updated my question with what I tried before posting this question.If possible help me.

Comment: So the `npm install aws-sdk` ends without any error in the console ?

Comment: Yes installing with out any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [NativeScript does not (yet) "polyfill" a crypto module](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/195) this could be a hard thing.

[Searching the code for references to `crypto`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/search?p=1&q=crypto&utf8=%E2%9C%93), you'll find that there's not that many uses and the uses are not that advanced. What this means is that you should be able to substitute the Node module *crypto* with [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) which works in a NativeScript environment.

You might need to fork the AWS SDK codebase and substitute the calls to the Node crypto module with calls to the corresponding methods in crypto-js. Unfortunately they do not share the same API.

If you're running Webpack (or anything like it) you should be able to create a "transformer module" which will transform Node crypto calls to the corresponding crypto-js calls and then make sure your transformer module is called instead of the Node crypto module via [Webpack alias'](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias).

Comment: Thanks for your response.I understood and tried what you suggested.I installed webpack in node js.But if I'm using **require("webpack");** in my nativescript file, app is getting crashed by saying failed to find module:"webpack".

Comment: Webpack is a bundler for Javascript. Think of it as a tool to build your Javascript) - not a module which you will include in your source code.

Comment: I'm exploring on what you suggested.I will update if I got a way to do that.If possible can you post or point me to an example it will be very helpful.Thanks.

Comment: Start with just forking the AWS SDK source code and edit it to see if you can get it to work with NativeScript. If that works, then figure our if you can substitute the crypto module without hacking the source. Webpack Alias is well defined in the link in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I recently had to figure this out so for future AWS-{N} integrators:

The easiest solution is to use the regular aws-sdk along with nativescript-nodeify. Instructions for aws and cognito are at the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify). It takes care of making a bunch of dependencies (i.e crypto, fs) NativeScript-compatible